# the sudoer can't restart ssh service on debian8.1

Tags: ssh

I have installed debina8.1 ,set the sudoers configuration this way.
1.apt-get update
2.apt-get install sudo
3.adduser test
4.usermod -a -G sudo test
When i connect vps with test account name, and change some port .

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 21388
Protocol 2 

 /etc/init.d/ssh  restart  #with test account name
[....] Restarting ssh (via systemctl): ssh.serviceFailed to restart ssh.service: Access denied
failed!
```

The test has sudo permission,why the command `/etc/init.d/ssh  restart`  can't work on the name of test?It is tested that the command `/etc/init.d/ssh  restart`  can  work on the name of root.

Comment: You didn't use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the permissions, most probably the ssh executable didn't have permission for the account you were using at that moment. For seeing which file has which permissions to who you can simply type `ls -l`, then you'll see something weird like

`drwxrwxr-x 2 pi acctg 1024 date time file name`

and maybe some more,
d in the beginning says its a directory, in your case it doesn't have a "d" in the beginning, instead there is "-" in the beginning, after first character other 9 characters are rwx , rwx and rwx again as you can see if they don't have dash,

r stands for read permission

w stands for write permission

x stand for execute permission,

First 3(after first character) (rwx or --- or r-- or other combinations) is for representing what permissions do the owner of that file have.

Second 3 is for representing what permissions do the other accounts in that group of that file have.

Third 3 is for represent is for the "Others"; everyone else.

If you want to have the permission for that test account what I suggest you to is, first read `man chmod` or this guide here : http://catcode.com/teachmod/ , it explains almost every outline, then decide if you want the permissions, because it might end up with some security problems.

**If you directly want to be able to execute :**

type : `sudo chmod 775/etc/init.d/ssh`

If you represent 7 in binary you'll see 111, it represents enable read permit, write permit and execute permit for Owner and Group and just enable read permit and execute permit for the others.

But I strongly suggest you to read the manuals before using it.